# how to use camelCase in IDEA live templates

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I constructed this live template:

```
public boolean is$var$Present() {
  return $varname$.isPresent();
}
```

[image]

I expect the variable name I type to be converted to camelCase and inserted to "return ...." string, but this does not happen. the "return ..." part stays unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

In **Live Templates Page**, you can click "**Edit variables**" to make connection between two or more variables.

In your case, you can set `$varname$` as `camelCase(var)`.

Screenshot:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA live template with function - sample (camelCase)]

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: I made same mistake as probably @Alex did - I expected camelCase (not sure why) to change `abc` to `Abc`.  List of functions is available [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html#predefined_functions).

Comment: It's a good idea to check "Skip if defined", it behave as expected, you are not requested to fill it in. With arrows one can change the order as well. It is a good idea to fill also "var" as default value, so you know what you are filling in.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:

```
public boolean is$capitalizedVar$Present() {
  return $var$.isPresent();
}
```

[image]